# JQuery Submit on Select

Tags: jquery, select, submit

I've found a snippet that adds autocomplete to a form:

http://jsfiddle.net/XxTuA/2/

The problem is that I can't figure out how to submit the form on select. Any help would be greatly appreciated:

```
var suggestCallBack; // global var for autocomplete jsonp

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#search").autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.getJSON("http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?callback=?",
                { 
                  "hl":"en", // Language                  
                  "jsonp":"suggestCallBack", // jsonp callback function name
                  "q":request.term, // query term
                  "client":"youtube" // force youtube style response, i.e. jsonp
                }
            );
            suggestCallBack = function (data) {
                var suggestions = [];
                $.each(data[1], function(key, val) {
                    suggestions.push({"value":val[0]});
                });
                suggestions.length = 5; // prune suggestions list to only 5 items
                response(suggestions);
            };
        },
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
   $("#search").autocomplete({
     select: function (event, ui) {
         var selectedObj = ui.item;              
          alert(selectedObj.value);
          $("#search").val(selectedObj.value);
         $('#formId').submit();
        },
        source: function(request, response) {


.................
```

Comment: Thank you. It seems to work partially. The form is submitted, but with the typed text, not with the selected text from the automatic suggestion...

Comment: @EliasP  did you checked it

Comment: well, the alert shows the proper selected automatic suggestion, but the form is still submitted just with the typed string...

Comment: @EliasP check it now.I changed my code by assiging the selected value to the field

Comment: That was it. Now it works great. This was definitely beyond me. Thank you very much!

Comment: with pleasure. just had to find the link in the interface :)